# ASP.NET MVC JsonResult and handlebars, no grip?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, handlebars.js

I'm looking at example of using hadlebars.js, where template processing looks like:

```
 var source   = $("#some-template").html();
 var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
 var data = { users: [
  {username: "alan", firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson", email: "alan@test.com" },
  {username: "allison", firstName: "Allison", lastName: "House", email: "allison@test.com" },
  {username: "ryan", firstName: "Ryan", lastName: "Carson", email: "ryan@test.com" }
]};
$("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));
```

and template is:

```
  <tbody>
  {{#users}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{username}}</td>
      <td>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</td>
      <td>{{email}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/users}}
</tbody>
```

Now I have JSON result from ASP.NET MVC and I can't think the way I should descripbe my template, because it does not have "users" property, it looks like:

```
{[{username: "alan", firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson", email: "alan@test.com" }]}
```

Can I somehow affect JsonResult to output what I need, or there is a way to fix template without touching the controller code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your controller replace:

```
return Json(users);
```

with:

```
return Json(new { users = users });
```

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, without introducing the anonymous object with the `users` property, you can change your template like so:

```
<tbody>
  {{#each this}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{username}}</td>
      <td>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</td>
      <td>{{email}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```